# Should I specify root files in tsconfig.json if Webpack is used?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

The [official handbook about *tsconfig.json*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) says:

> The tsconfig.json file specifies the root files and the compiler options required to compile the project.

As far as I understand, the root files of *tsconfig.json* are the files that `tsc` should compile by default (i.e. no files are passed explicitly). According to the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), I can use the "files" or "exclude" property to define the root files.

> If no "files" property is present in a tsconfig.json, the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (*.ts or *.tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories. When a "files" property is present, only the specified files are included.
>
> If the "exclude" property is specified, the compiler includes all TypeScript (*.ts or *.tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories except for those files or folders that are excluded.
>
> The "files" property cannot be used in conjunction with the "exclude" property. If both are specified then the "files" property takes precedence.

I'm not using `tsc` directly. Instead, I'm using [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to compile my TypeScript files. Therefore, I'm using [hjs-webpack](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/hjs-webpack) which uses [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader):

**webpack.config.js**

```
var getConfig = require('hjs-webpack');

var config = getConfig({
  in: 'src/index.ts',
  out: 'public',
  clearBeforeBuild: true
});

module.exports = config;
```

I specify all entry points in my *webpack.config.js*. If I understand it right, [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader) tells `tsc` that those entry files are the root files. That would mean that the "files" and "exclude" property of *tsconfig.json* are always ignored by `tsc`. Is this right?

I often see an "exclude" property in *jsconfig.json* of Webpack projects. Best example is [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) (another TypeScript loader for Webpack), which mentions this configuration step:

> 2. Add a tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

If "files" and "exclude" property of *tsconfig.json* are always ignored if only Webpack is used for compilation, why should I specify "files" or "exclude" property in *tsconfig.json*?

---

Please write a comment, if you need further information (e.g. about my setup) to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you are using **webpack** for compile then you don't need to include it, you simply point to your only ts files to be compiled. Your loader will look for the tsconfig file for compilation config. It's has no purpose in webapp.

[here is an example of webpack angular2 typescript seed i'm working on](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed)

Comment: So if it is not needed, why did you add `"exclude": [ "node_modules" ]` to the [tsconfig of your webpack project](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed/blob/master/tsconfig.json)?

Comment: that's for i don't want to tsconfig look into node_modules and it's optional so you can remove it becouse webpack take care of it and i'm also gonna remove it :-)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. *tsconfig* cann't look into *node_modules*, only tools (like `tsc` or Webpack). If you don't want *tsconfig* to look into *node_modules*, which tool are you refering to? I asked, if using the `exclude` property has any effect on my Webpack build. You said that I don't need to include it. Consequently, it doesn't have any effect. That means Webpack doesn't take the `exclude` property of *tsconfig* into account. So you don't refer to Wepack, are you?

Comment: It's a config file witch mean whatever i specifies in that config file tools like tsc or ts-loader will read and work against that specification, you can see in my webpack.config that i'm excluding node_modules even there. you can read more about it in [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader)

Comment: Thank you so far. I rewrote my question to go into more detail what I mean by "no effect". In my understanding, the "exclude" property is always ignored, since root files are passed explicitly to `tsc` by Webpack's TypeScript loader.

Comment: You don't need to specify root files in **tsconfig** if you are using  **webpack**.you specify them in webpack if you want to use webpack for bundle, compilation and extra. webpack's specification.

Comment: So I'm right: "files" and "exclude" property should not be specified if Webpack is used. Otherwise, it is only confusing, at least for me ;-)

Comment: Yes I couldn't explain better because of doing it from mobile :-) then may be you can accept my answer ? :-)